# What's the best way to add taxonomy's image in 2017?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-field, uploads, media-library, media-modal

Need to build image upload for custom taxonomies. I used `Categories Images` plugin before, but now I need 2 images and this plugin doesn't fit anymore.
I'm looking for a best solution. Does anybody knows it in 2017?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something I use generally.. Please refer this [link](https://en.bainternet.info/wordpress-taxonomies-extra-fields-the-easy-way/) . and follow. This will help you definitel
thanks